# S.E.M.F. physics C++ code

Tags: c++, physics

Need some help to solve one minor issue with this program. I have created the S.E.M.F. in physics for C++ to calculate the formula everything is great but my B.E. formula with a5 in it.

It says Error: Identifier "a5" is undefined and I know what it means but how would I get that a5 to take from the Selection Statement, if I input even even or even odd or odd odd for my A Z values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int A, Z;

    // Main body of Semi-Empirical Mass Formula
    cout <<"Enter the mass number A: ";
    cin >> A;
    cout <<"\n";
    cout <<"Enter the atomic number Z: ";
    cin >> Z;
    cout <<"\n";

    // Constants from formula, units in MeV(millions of electron volts)
    double a1 = 15.67;          
    double a2 = 17.23;
    double a3 = 0.75;
    double a4 = 93.2;

    if(Z % 2 == 0 && (A - Z) % 2 == 0)

        double a5 = 12.0;

    else if(Z % 2 != 0 && (A - Z) % 2 != 0)

        double a5 = -12.0;

    else

        double a5 = 0;


    // Formula for to compute the binding energy
    double B =a1 * A - a2 * pow( A, 2/3) - a3 * (pow(Z, 2) / pow(A, 1/3)) - a4 * (pow(A - 2 * Z, 2) / A) + (a5 / pow(A, 1/2));

    // Formula for to compute the binding energy per nucleon
    double B_E = B / A;


    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You can just declare the variable outside the `if` clause: `double a5 = 0;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the definition of

```
double a5 = 0.0;
```

just below the a4 definition, and use it in each of your ifs cases.

Comment: By the way; in 'Formula' 2/3 == 0; as 1/3 and 1/2, because of integer division; you should write 2.0/3.0, 1.0/2.0 and 1.0/2.0 instead.

Answer (score 6):

a5 is undefined due to a scope issue.

Because you declare a5 within the clauses of an if -- else statement, the declaration only has scope within the statement that it is declared.

To fix this problem, declare a5 in a spot where its scope extends to the later statements where you are using a5:

```
double a1 = 15.67;          
double a2 = 17.23;
double a3 = 0.75;
double a4 = 93.2;
double a5 = 0.0;
//^ declare a5 here, it will be in scope when used in subsequent statements past the else clause


if(Z % 2 == 0 && (A - Z) % 2 == 0)

    a5 = 12.0;

else if(Z % 2 != 0 && (A - Z) % 2 != 0)

    a5 = -12.0;


// Formula for to compute the binding energy
double B =a1 * A - a2 * pow( A, 2/3) - a3 * (pow(Z, 2) / pow(A, 1/3)) - a4 * (pow(A - 2 * Z, 2) / A) + (a5 / pow(A, 1/2));
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to declare `a5` outside your if statements and then set it in the if statements

```
double a5 = 0;

if(Z % 2 == 0 && (A - Z) % 2 == 0)
    a5 = 12.0;
else if(Z % 2 != 0 && (A - Z) % 2 != 0)
    a5 = -12.0;
```

As you have it right now the variable `a5` will only exist inside the if statement it is declared in.

Answer (score 2):

Just move the declaration of `a5` up a bit:

```
double a5;
if(Z % 2 == 0 && (A - Z) % 2 == 0)
    a5 = 12.0;
else if(Z % 2 != 0 && (A - Z) % 2 != 0)
    a5 = -12.0;
else
    a5 = 0;
```